# Помогите! Я не могу понять как можно выровнять ссылку в своем блоке

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

вот **HTML:** и **CSS:**

```css
dropdown-child-b{
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 17.5%;
    text-align: center;
}

div{
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 17.5%;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-menu">
 <div class="menu-top">текст
  </div>
  <div class="menu">текст</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="news">меню</div>
      <div class="dropdown-child">     
      <a  class="dropdown-child-a"href="#" >
      1
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-child-a2" >
          <a  href="#" >
           <div class="dropdown2">
               <div class="news2">1.2
               </div>
               <div class="dropdown-child2">
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a   href="#" >2.1
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a href="#">
                          2.2
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a href="#" >
                          2.3
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a   href="#" >
                      </a>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ссылки по центру ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, вы имели в виду выравнивание текста по горизонтали.
Для начала, селекторы классов начинайте с `.` 
1) Старайтесь в файле стилей вводить селекторы по мере их появления в древе вёрстки. Например, `div` "по-хорошему" должен стоять в начале т.к этот селектор глобальнее, если вам понадобиться этот тэг изменить в зависимости от класса, то в вашем случае это не сработает т.к селектор `div{}` стоит позже - следовательно он сработает позже  и покажется в итоге. Также не надо писать одинаковые по значению свойства для элементов, которые вложены в друг друга т.е у вас для `div` прописан фон, и для вложенного в него `div` прописано тоже самое. Какой смысл тег `a` делать блочным?
 **РЕШЕНИЕ**
Пропишите `width: 17.5;` **только** для тега с меню, или другого родительского контейнера. У вас получается так, что для ВСЕХ `div` ширина 17,5 пикселей, следовательно у вложенных элементов отчёт ширины будет не от экрана, а от `div` **родителя!**
Вообще у вас много лишних `div` и пустых `a`, но я их трогать не стал. Старайтесь всегда упрощать и подкреплять семантикой вёрстку. 
В итоге я просто прописал всем `div` `text-align: center;`

Вот выглядит законченный вариант:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-menu{
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 17.5%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu-menu">
  <div class="menu-top">текст</div>
  <div class="menu">текст</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="news">меню</div>
      <div class="dropdown-child">     
        <a  class="dropdown-child-a"href="#" >
          1
        </a>
      <div class="dropdown-child-a2" >
        <a  href="#" >
          <div class="dropdown2">
               <div class="news2">1.2
               </div>
               <div class="dropdown-child2">
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a   href="#" >2.1
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a href="#">2.2
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a href="#" >
                          2.3
                      </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown-child-b" >
                      <a   href="#" >
                      </a>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Надеюсь, я вам помог, удачи в изучении!